# can't submit form which contains invisible li

Tags: css, forms, html-lists

I have 4 li's under ul.

I made two of them hidden using visisblity css rule.

all this is contained inside a form. 
The problem is when the two li is in hidden mode I can't submit the form. I checked with firebug and he is reporting no error.

Does anybody know whats the problem.

code

```
    <form>
       <ul>
        <li class="cssClass" id="1" style="visibility:hidden">
        <li class="cssClass" id="2" style="visibility:hidden">
        <li class="cssClass" id="3" style="visibility:visible">
        <li class="cssClass" id="4" style="visibility:visible">
      </ul>
    </form>

   <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="submit" key="form.submit" />" />
```

Comment: how are you posting your form?

Comment: That `input` tag should be inside the `form` tags, otherwise it definitely won't work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `<input>` tag is not within the `<form>`.

When you trigger a `type="submit"` element, it submits the enclosing `form`. That, here, is nothing.